# Font Info Program Name Clash Probem

Tags: fonts

I have had problems getting the **autoinst** program to install an **OpenType** font family in my **TeX/LaTeX** tree. After making desperate and frustratingly long efforts I discovered that my system had two different **otfinfo** programs: (a) The **otfinfo** program used by the **openmpi** --- **/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin/otfinfo**; and (b) the **otfinfo** program used by the autoinst program --- **/usr/bin/otfinfo**. I discovered, after doing **otfinfo --help**, that **autoinst** had been trying to use the **otfinfo** program which is meant for use by the **openmpi**.

I work in a SUSE 13.1 environment. There may be other TeX/LaTeX users who may have experienced problems with the **autoinst** program, as I did, probably due to the name clash problem.

I succeeded in using the **autoinst** program by renaming the **otfinfo** program which is meant for use by the **openmpi**. However, I consider this to be a temporary solution. (I may need the other **otfinfo** program soon.)

Does someone have an idea of how one could get the two **otfinfo** programs to live together happily in a system under the same name?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Isn't this more a question for Linux/SuSe?

Comment: Just specify the full path, `/usr/bin/otfinfo` when you want to use the `otfinfo` which is second in your path. Or create an alias. For example, in `bash` or `sh`, you could use something like `alias otfinfo-autoinst='/usr/bin/otfinfo'` and put that in one of your shell startup scripts such as `~/.bashrc` or whatever. But this is not really a TeX question.